# How can I create new lists in a loop and name them so I can fill them up with items from another list using Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, list-comprehension

I made a double for loop that first takes a word from a list of radicals and then iterates through the same list looking for similar words (with a ratio of 70%). 
What I need is that each time the first loop takes a word from the list, it creates a new list containing the word + those that were chosen by the second loop that are similar.

I tried a lot with lists comprehensions but I can't figure out how to put the words from the second loop into the new list. I thought it could work if each list created had an index (x).
Here's my code :

```
x = 0

result = [[] for x in range(len(radicals))]
for i in range(0, len(radicals)) : 
    for j in range(1, len(radicals)) : 
        result[x].append(words[i]) 
        result[x].append(words[j])     
print(result[0])
```

The result I got is the number of words in radicals * the number of list...

The words list :

```
words = ["flore", "fleur", "fleuriste", "remaniement", "remanier", "manier", "maniable", "désaimer", "aimer", "aimant", "mêler", "emmêler", "désemmêler"]
```

The result after print(radicals) :

```
['flore', 'fleur', 'fleur', 'manie', 'mani', 'mani', 'mani', 'aim', 'aim', 'aim', 'mêl', 'mêl', 'emmêl']
```

I'm trying to put words and not radicals in new lists, I only need radicals for the matching process.

I need to have something like :

```
['flore', 'fleur', 'fleuriste']
['manier', 'remanier', 'remaniement']
['désaimer', 'aimer', 'aimant']
['mêler', 'emmêler', 'désemmêler']
```

I could really use your help. Thanks a lot !

Comment: you realize you're using the same variable name for both your variables and your `for` loop iterations? the only variable actually being used is `x`

Comment: Could you provide an example of `radicals` and expected result?

Comment: @KirillErmolov I just edited my question :)

Comment: @mangoHero1  x creates as many lists as there are items in radicals, what I tried is to use [x] as an index for the lists such as result[0] = first list created, result[1] = second... of course it doesn't work this way but I don't understand your comment since i and j iterates well the radicals list ?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is you don't need to declare a variable (`i = 0`) to use one in a for loop (`for i in range(len(radicals))`)

Comment: @mangoHero1 Okay thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
def is_match(radical_1, radical_2):
    # return true if two radical are the same.

# ...    

n = len(radicals)
result = []
used_js = []
for i in range(n):
    if i in used_js:
        continue
    matches = [words[i]]
    js = (x for x in range(n) if x != i and x not in used_js)
    for j in js:
        if is_match(radicals[i], radicals[j]):
            matches.append(words[j])
            used_js.append(j)
    result.append(matches)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kirill Ermolov, it works perfectly !